# Are Green functions non-perturbatively infrared finite?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, infrared-radiation, non-perturbative

Are Green functions non-perturbatively infrared finite?
In other words imagine one had the final form of the 4-point function for spin-1/2 field, do we still need infrared radiation correction?
In other words shouldn't Green functions be finite (non-perturbatively) excluding any bremsstrahlung radiation correction?

Comment: all order in perturbation theory is almost certainly not the same as nonperturbative as perturbation theory probbaly is divergent for nontrivial physical theories like QED or QCD

Comment: Yes. Probably the language went abit sloppy! Suppose God has given the final forms of the 4-point function non-Perturbatively, Do we still need IR regularization?

Comment: One of the Wightman axioms for QFT is clustering, which is essentially a rigorous statement about the finiteness of the IR limit.

Comment: Could you please explain more?